# Google Ads Conversion Actions - Do you need both a GA4 Purchase event and GoogleAds Conversion event measuring the same thing?

Tags: google-ads, google-analytics-4

I've just been trying to get my head around the difference between GA4 "Purchase" events and Google Ads "Conversion" events.

The Google Ads set-up I am looking at has the GA4 Purchase event configured as the primary conversion, and measures a product being purchased. This sends the appropriate price data and order details along with it.

The Google Ads Conversion event is set as the secondary event, and is also fired on the site's purchase page, but doesn't send price data due to how the CMS I am using is built.  Both events are fired at the same time via a single gtag.

However, I've been told by the marketing team that the latter event also needs to also send price data.

My assumption is that the Google Ads Conversion event is currently duplicating the GA4 Purchase event for absolutely no reason and so is unnecessary.  I'd assume that the intention of a secondary event is to measure something different (eg contact form submission).

If I'm wrong here, why would you need to send the same information twice via two different methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is secondary, I would say it does not matter. And I'd agree its presence does not matter.

Secondary events are not used to aid advertising. They are for observation only.

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/11461796

I'd stick with your GA4 purchase while your ads conversion event is incomplete.

It is possible to send more useful data to ads via the ads tag, but it sounds like that's not possible for you at the moment:

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9028254